# How can I generate a spreadsheet containing links for all folders within a Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, hyperlink

I have a Document Library that contains about 100,000 folders (tickets from Remedy), and each ticket (folder) has 1-5 files associated with it. All ticket folders are on the same level hierarchy with respect to the root folder, if that makes sense. Also, each ticket is prefixed with three characters to denote the nature of the ticket. Folder names are the same as the ticket ID.

What I'd like to do is, create a custom view for each ticket category (prefix), and then, for each record (ticket) within each custom view, provide a link to the Document Library, specifically to the folder that contains all attachments for the given ticket.

My concern is: **How can I obtain a spreadsheet that contains the links to each ticket attachment folder within the Document Library?** Manually doing this would of course be insane.

Comment: Do you need just a spreadsheet with the folder links or a SharePoint view also?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Create a view with "Group By" in the same library that has 100k folders.

1. Create a calculated column "Prefix" with formula below.

   ```
   =LEFT(Title,3)
   ```
2. Create a view and use Group By on "Prefix"

A sample looks this

[image]

**Solution 2**

Enable the "Metadata navigation settings" on the document library as below. This gives a navigation tree view on the left navigation.

[image]

[image]

**Solution 3**

Use custom code. You need to loop through the folders recursively, read the folder with pattern "data_xxxx", generate the url as a string and store it back to the root level in an hyperlink field. You need to add that hyperlink field to the "folder" content type.

Comment: Hmm.. I do like the idea of grouping by the prefix, however, the attachment files for each ticket aren't stored in the root folder of that ticket. Which is to say, the user would still have to navigate through a series of folders to get to the attachments, given the approach you offer.

Comment: Could you brief how the ticket and related attachments are structured? Can you give example of a ticket with its attachments as a tree structure?

Comment: @AhmadZai Sure, it's really simple. For each ticket there's a folder that's titled the same as the ticket ID. Within that folder, there's a data file that contains the form that the ticket was created by, and then, there's a subfolder that's titled "data_xxxxxxxxxxx", which contains all the attachment files. The "xxxxxxxxxxx" is completely random, but the hierarchy is consist in this way. So, the attachment folder directory would be, "\\rootFolder\ticketID\data_xxx\".

Comment: @Charles thank you for the brief. I have edited my answer. Please refer to the Solution 2 in my answer.